# How to get the string out of a StringProperty in Python

Tags: python, kivy

I have a kivy label bound to a `StringProperty()`. I'm trying to get the string out of it in Python.

```
class Screen1(Screen):
    food_label = StringProperty()

    def print_label(self):
        print(Screen1.food_label)
```

It returns this:
`<StringProperty name=food_label>`

I set the property on the previous screen using this statement in a `def`:

```
self.manager.get_screen('screen_1').food_label = food
```

Where 'food' is a `String`. On the screen the label text is displayed correctly.

How can I print the actual string contained in the `StringProperty()`.

Comment: @kindall I get an error `get() takes exactly one argument (0 given)`. Not sure what argument I need to add to it... This part is not stated in the docs.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that call needs to be on an instance, like `self.manager.get_screen('screen_1').food_label.get()`

Comment: @kindall yep, that did it. TY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Screen1.food_label` would not work. While kivy properties look like Python static variables given that they are declared at the top of the class, they are actually object properties. If you would have done

```
class Screen1(Screen):
    food_label = 'Hello world'

    def print_label(self):
        print(Screen1.food_label)
```

This should work
 But since these are Kivy Properties, you have to do

```
class Screen1(Screen):
    food_label = StringProperty()

    def print_label(self):
        print(self.food_label)
```